# Number of Linear Factors of $x^{\frac{p-1}{2}}-1$ in $\mathbb{Z}_p$

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, field-theory

In my number theory class, I was given the following problem:
How many linear factors does the polynomial $x^{\frac{p-1}{2}}-1$ have over $\mathbb{Z}_p$, where $p$ is an odd prime?

I'm not sure how to start this. Going just from looks, I might try to use Euler's criterion and then results about the amount of squares mod p, but I'm not really sure if that's applicable here because $x$ is indeterminate. What can I do to solve this?

Comment: Do you know how many linear factors the polynomial $x^{p-1}-1$ has over ${\bf Z}_p$? Hint – Fermat.

Comment: Well it must be that $x^{p-1} \equiv 1$, which by Fermat's last theorem means that if gcd(x,p)=1, we're good. Since p is prime, we have this for every $x$ in $\mathbb{Z}_p$, so is the answer p-1? I also don't see how this helps with $x^{\frac{p-1}{2}}-1$

Comment: Fermat's *Little* Theorem, not Fermat's Last Theorem. Yes, $x^{p-1}-1$ has $p-1$ linear factors. Now, $p$ is odd, so $p-1$ is even, which should give you an idea about factoring $x^{p-1}-1$.

Comment: Of course, obviously not Fermat's last theorem haha. So if p-1 is even then p-1 = 2m for some m, then $x^{p-1}-1=x^{2m}-1=(x^m-1)(x^m+1)$. I'm not sure what to do at this point or if this is the right approach. What I can say is that since the characteristic $p$ of $\mathbb{Z}_p$ does not divide $m$, the polynomial $x^m-1$ has no repeated factors. I'm not sure if this second bit is even useful, and I don't know how to deal with $x^m+1$.

Comment: OK. So, we have $x^{p-1}-1$ has $p-1$ linear factors. What's the greatest possible number of linear factors $x^m+1$ could have? And what does that say about the number of linear factors of $x^m-1$?

Comment: I don't know. Via the fundamental theorem of algebra both of these have at most m roots?

Comment: Exactly! They each have at most $m$ roots, which means at most $m$ linear factors (although technically this isn't from the Fundamental Theorem of Algebra, it's just a fact about polynomials with coefficients in a field). And together, they have exactly $p-1$ linear factors. That tells you exactly how many linear factors each of the two polynomials has. Right?

Answer (score -1):

$x^{\frac{p-1}{2}}-1 \equiv 0$(mod p)

$\iff (\frac{x}{p})=1$ which has exactly $\frac{p-1}{2}$ solutions[matches with degree of orginal polynomial] and are

$1^2,2^2,...,(\frac{p-1}{2})^2$ mod p

so $x^{\frac{p-1}{2}}-1=(x-1^2)...(x-(\frac{p-1}{2})^2)$ in $Z_p$

hence $\frac{p-1}{2}$ linear factors